# How to bootstrap / connect to another Craft instance from inside a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, bootstrap-craft

I'm currently writing a plugin which should connect to another Craft Instance (same server, same `app` folder) and run some code (start a task or execute a service function).

I looked at the [`bootstrap.php`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/bootstrap.php) which looks great, but I can't include it inside the plugin, or can I somehow?

So how can I bootstrap / connect to another Craft instance from inside my plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to load it up from your plugin.

```
public function init()
{
    $otherCraftApp = require '/path/to/other/bootstrap.php';
    $otherCraftHttpRequestService = $otherCraftApp->request;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, because it's the same `app` folder, so I'm basically including itself. Or do I have to create a `bootstrap.php` outside the `app`-folder for each instance?

Comment: Ahh, missed the "share the same app folder" part. `bootstrap.php` is coded to assume it's living immediately inside of the `app` folder. I assume the two sites have separate public `index.php` files?

Comment: Yes, separate `index.php`, config, template and plugin files.

Comment: Doesn't this break the licensing?

Comment: @LukeHolder Each instance has its own `config` folder, with its own `license.key` file, so it doesn't break the licensing.

Answer (score 1):

As I am not able to comment I am leaving a braindump...

I assume you try to trigger actions/tasks whatever in a environment like devmaster <-- dev, a dev <-- stage or something similar.

If that is the case:
I was looking at that already as well but found utilizing a cron job or puppet script be more
- secure and controllable (also in case a developer leaves the company)
- scalable in regards to performance and security also accross   systems/clusters/dokku boxes)
- more reliable and granular as it allows more detailed logging/repoting options in case of a failure (snapin for the dashboard could utilize system logs and related data, you just need a template and no conversion)

As I am still in a concept phase for my project, I cant provide a working sample yet, sorry.